# Convergence of $\sum\ln(n\sin\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How to prove that $\sum\ln(n\sin\frac{1}{n})$ converges rigorously?

The idea is to expand $\sin(t)$ and $\ln(1+t)$. But I'm not sure how to do it rigorously. We have $n\sin(1/n)=n(1/n+O(1/n^3))=1+nO(1/n^3)$ as $n\to \infty$. Then I need to substitute it into $\ln (1+t)=t-t^2/2+O(t^3)$. (Or should I use the little o in one of both cases?) This involves taking powers of $nO(1/n^3)$ (or of the little o) and multiplying it by functions, and I'm not very familiar how the o's behave under such operations (and not aware of any source to find that out). So how to do the prove in a rigorous way?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089232/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-ln-bign-sin-frac1n-big-converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by Taylor’s expansion we have

- $\sin \left(\frac1n \right)= \frac1n+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$

therefore

$$\ln\left(n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln (1+O(1/n^2))=O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

and the given series converges by limit comparison test with $\sum 1/n^2$.

More in detail we have

- $\sin \left(\frac1n \right)= \frac1n-\frac1{6n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)$

therefore

$$\ln\left(n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln \left(1-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)=$$
$$=-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)+O\left[\left(-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)^2\right]=-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

indeed

$$O\left[\left(-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)^2\right]=O\left[\frac1{36n^4}-2\frac1{6n^2}O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^8}\right)\right]=$$
$$=O\left[\frac1{36n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^8}\right)\right]=O\left[\frac1{36n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)\right]=O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

indeed by definition

$$\frac1{36n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)=O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

since

$$\left|\frac{\frac1{36n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)}{\frac1{n^4}}\right|\to \frac1{36}$$

and

$$O\left[O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right]=O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

since

$$\left|\frac{O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)}{\frac1{n^4}}\right|\to L< \infty$$

and finally

$$\ln\left(n\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)=O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

indeed by definition

$$\left|\frac{-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)}{\frac1{n^2}}\right|\to \frac1{6}$$

Comment: Let $x=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $\frac{sinx}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+...$ Therefor $ln(nsin\frac{1}{n})$ first term is $-\frac{1}{6n^2}$.  The remainder is $O(\frac{1}{n^4})$.

Comment: Note that the following holds $$-1/(6n^2)+O(1/n^4)=O(1/n^2)$$ Therefore is not necessary use the LHS form for the expansion.

Comment: You are right, but I wasn't sure what he wanted to do with the approximation.

Comment: The expression $O(1/n^2)$ suffices to apply limit comparison test.

Comment: $\ln(1+t)=t+O(t^2)$. But your last formula says just $\ln(1+t)=t$ for $t=O(1/n^2)$. Why is it the same? It were such details that caused my confusions before I asked this question.

Comment: If you like to expand more you can but it is not necessary. We have that $\ln (1+t)=t+o(t)=t+O(t^2)=O(t)$.

Comment: @user531299 I'm going to add some detail more in order to try to clarify your doubts.

Comment: Then I guess we need to prove $O((O(1/n^2))^2)=O(1/n^2)$...

Comment: @user531299 No it is not, we have $O((O(1/n^2))^2)=O(1/n^4)$.

Comment: Not sure what definition of $O(x)$ you are using; I thought $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means $|f(x)/g(x)|< M$ (but you are using limits). Anyway I guess your definition implies mine since if there is a limit, then the function is bounded. But I'm not sure I understand why e.g. $1/36+O(1/n^2)$ is bounded. The second summand is only bounded  when divided by $1/n^2$ but not on its own.

Comment: @user531299 Yes it can be also defined as a limit. For the other doubt, for some $M>0$ we have $|O(1/n^2)|\le M\cdot (1/n^2)\to 0$$ therefore $|O(1/n^2)|\to 0$ and $1/36+|O(1/n^2)|$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. For the equality $O(1/n^4)^2=O(1/n^8)$, is it valid to write $|O(1/n^4)^2/(1/n^8)|=|[n^4\cdot O(1/n^4)]\cdot [n^4\cdot O(1/n^4]|=|O(1)O(1)|< M$?

Comment: @user531299 More simply $$|O(1/n^4)|\le M\cdot (1/n^4)\implies|(O(1/n^4))^2|\le M^2\cdot (1/n^8) $$

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series of $\sin x$ is 
$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^5)$$
Hence
$$\sin \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{6n^3} + O(\frac{1}{n^5})$$
So
$$n\sin \frac{1}{n} = 1- \frac{1}{6n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})$$
Taylor series of $\ln$ is 
$$\ln(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$$
For $x = -\frac{1}{6n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})$, we get
$$\ln(1 - \frac{1}{6n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})) = -\frac{1}{6n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})$$
Then you'd get a sum of convergent series since all those sums have $p > 1$ according to the p-series test.

Comment: Why did you omit $O(x^2)$ in the last display (where $x$ is defined one line above)?

Comment: You could include them i.e. take $x = -\frac{1}{6n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})$ and evaluate $\ln(1+x) = x + O(x^2)$, you will see that you will arrive at the same conclusion, namely: you'd get a sum of convergent series since all those sums have p>1 according to the p-series test.

Comment: The major part of my confusion stems from not being sure how to compute/simplify things like $O((-\frac{1}{6n^2}+O(1/n^4))^2)$.

Comment: Okay think about $O(1/n^4)$ as being a scalar multiple of $1/n^4$, so replace it with something like $c/n^4$ for constant $c$. Expand $O((-\frac{1}{6n^2}+O(1/n^4))^2)$ after replacing  $O(1/n^4)$ with $c/n^4$. You will then get a form $\alpha \frac{1}{n^4} + \beta \frac{1}{n^6} + \gamma \frac{1}{n^8}$, which are all negligible when faced in front of $-\frac{1}{6n^2}$, right ?

Answer (score 1):

The series is convergent.

For large $n$ you can write $n \sin(\frac{1}{n}) = 1-\frac{1}{6 n^2} +O(1/n^4)$ and because $\log(1-x) \simeq -x$ the summand becomes $-\frac{1}{6 n^2}$ and this gives the convergent series for the Riemann zeta function of argument 2.